# String tokenization code gets stuck in while loop

Tags: c++, tokenize

The task was to find all the words in array `s` with numbers inside them. The word are spaced with `" "` and at the end of the array there is always a `.`.

My code doesn't exit the `while` loop and I don't know why:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
void Numbers(char s[], vector<pair<int, char>>& nums){
    char *token;
    int zero = 0;
    token = strtok(s, " ");
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(token); i++){
        if(isdigit(token[i])){
            nums.emplace_back(zero, *token);
        }
    }
    while(token != NULL){
        zero ++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(token); i++){
            if(isdigit(token[i])){
                nums.emplace_back(zero, *token);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    vector<pair<int, char>> nums;
    char s[256];
    gets(s);
    Numbers(s, nums);
    cout << nums.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i ++){
        cout << nums[i].first << " " << nums[i].second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to run the code with `qw6wqe esd9f 0gfgkj.` input with debug, `token` changes, all should be working, but it never gets out of the loop.

Tried using `break` but that didn't work.

Comment: @МихайлоГорак See: [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: @МихайлоГорак [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/e3Yz9are9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour. When you reach the end of the input, `token` is a null pointer, and you then pass it to `strlen`.

You need to stop processing when `strtok` returns a null pointer.

```
void Numbers(char s[], vector<pair<int, char>>& nums){
    int count = 0;
    for(char * token = strtok(s, " "); token = strtok(nullptr, " ");){
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(token); i++){
            if(isdigit(token[i])){
                nums.emplace_back(count, *token);
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `nums.emplace_back(count, *token)` should presumably be `nums.emplace_back(count, token[i])`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Perhaps, or it might want to be filling `vector<pair<int, string>> nums`